# Closing Application Automatically When I Click - Android

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I'm a new programmer on Android. 
I'm trying create an application which has 2 buttons. 
I want to send a HTMLpost if you click first one. And for second one i want to create a new activity.
But when i click "YES" on the dialog box for first one, application closes.
The some thing occurs when i want to create new activity. I just click second one and application closes automatically.

I cant understand what is going on wrong. Can you help me? 
Thank you!

This is the MainActivity.java:

package com.onur.proje;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;
    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAlert);

        // add button listener
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Do you want to run it?");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Your Choice?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("YES",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                          // put the address to your server and receiver file here
                      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://yoursite/yourPHPScript.php");
                          try {
                             List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                                 // message is the parameter we are receiving, it has the value of 1 which is the value that will be sent from your server to your Arduino board
                             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", "1"));
                           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                           httpclient.execute(httppost); // send the parameter to the server
                         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                         } catch (IOException e) {
                             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                         }
                          dialog.cancel();
                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("NO",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        // Capture button clicks
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Start NewActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        NewActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
}
}
```

New Activity.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class NewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from new_activity.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.new_activity);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.onur.proje.MainActivity" >

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/buttonAlert"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
      android:text="RUN IT" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/buttonAlert"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
      android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

new_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you add new activity in the menifest ? ?

Comment: post logcat if you have an error

Comment: Oh, i forgot to add in manifest. Now it works. Thanks HarrY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing a Network Request on the UI thread in the Dialog's onClick... this should produce an `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`, and causes your app to crash.

You should use an `AsyncTask` or just create a new thread to execute your network request in the background.

EDIT: I just noticed, that you are using one variable for both of you buttons... so, you never enter in the logic for the network request, as you are setting a new reference to the `button` variable, which is pointing to the second button, with a new `onClickListener`...

Answer (score 0):

You  have  wrote  two button click listener for single  Id .....  U have  added button only  not  got  button alert.. Add I'd for  button alert  and  one  click  listener for  button another for  button alert.. I'd

public class MainActivity extends Activity { final Context context = this; private Button button; public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAlert); // add button listener button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View arg0) { AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder( context); // set title alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Do you want to run it?"); // set dialog message alertDialogBuilder .setMessage("Your Choice?") .setCancelable(false) .setPositiveButton("YES",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) { HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // put the address to your server and receiver file here HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://yoursite/yourPHPScript.php"); try { List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(2); // message is the parameter we are receiving, it has the value of 1 which is the value that will be sent from your server to your Arduino board nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", "1")); httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); httpclient.execute(httppost); // send the parameter to the server } catch (ClientProtocolException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block } catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block } dialog.cancel(); } }) .setNegativeButton("NO",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) { // if this button is clicked, just close // the dialog box and do nothing dialog.cancel(); } }); // create alert dialog AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create(); // show it alertDialog.show(); } }); button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); // putt another  I'd for button  alert  here   Capture button clicks button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View arg0) { // Start NewActivity.class Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class); startActivity(myIntent); } }); } }